# R: Exact size and location of a plotted character

Tags: r, plot, text

I'm trying to use `text(..., cex = ...)` to write a word which characters become incrementally smaller. However, I am struggling to get the position and alignment of each character right, as every character takes up less space than the previous. When rotating the text using `srt`, the positioning is even harder.

Is there perhaps a way to ask R the exact location and size of a placed character, such that I know where to place the next? Thanks!

For example, without using `srt`:

```
x.range <- c(0, 1)
y.range <- c(0, 1)
plot(NA, xlim = x.range, ylim = y.range, asp = 1)

w <- "incrementally smaller text"
n <- nchar(w)
shrink <- 0.025 # How much the text shrinks from one character to the next

for(i in 1:n){
  current <- substr(w, i, i)
  o <- shrink * diff(x.range) # some offset from the previous char
  text(x = x.range[1] + o * (i - 1), y = y.range[1], current,
       cex = (1 - shrink) ^ i)
}
```

Which produces the following (I underlined the text in an image editor to highlight the issue):

[image: ugly alignment]

Or for diagonal text:

```
x.range <- c(0, 1)
y.range <- c(0, 1)
plot(NA, xlim = x.range, ylim = y.range, asp = 1)

w <- "incrementally smaller text"
n <- nchar(w)
shrink <- 0.025 # How much the text shrinks from one character to the next

for(i in 1:n){
  current <- substr(w, i, i)
  x.o <- shrink * diff(x.range) # some horizontal offset from the previous char
  y.o <- shrink * diff(y.range) # some vertical offset from the previous char
  text(x = x.range[1] + x.o * (i - 1), y = y.range[2] - y.o * (i - 1)/3, current,
       cex = (1 - shrink) ^ i, srt = -15)
}
```

Which produces:

[image]

Can anyone explain to me what is going on here? The alignment appears to be all over the place.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Can you add reproducible code and matching plot? `adj` allows you to specify the position adjustment within `text` with respect to a horizontal and vertical reference point. By default text is horizontally centred.

Comment: I added a minimal working example and a figure of what I am trying to accomplish. My problem is how to correctly calculate the offset, such that the alignment does not go up and down, and such that the distance between the characters is appropriate.